# Packing thousands of files into an archvie using 7-zip "Store" compression. Does this significantly speed up a file transfer?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have a folder with 40,000 jpg images, and I'm assuming that if I pack them into a 7zip file using the "Store" compression level it would make file transfers a lot faster since the the 40k files would be recognized as one file? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You're not wrong, smaller compressed file size wise and all in one packed file both can mean better transfer performance depending on various factors. You can easily test this before and after and confirm for yourself with the same files and packed files in your environment to know for sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does copying the same amount of data take longer if spread across many separate files?](https://superuser.com/questions/344534/why-does-copying-the-same-amount-of-data-take-longer-if-spread-across-many-separ)

Comment: On the other hand you now have to add the compression and decompression time to the transfer time.

Comment: 'Store' does no compression or decompression.