# Why is there writing activity on the source device when copying data to the destination device in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

My embedded Linux system has two block devices:

- SD card: `/dev/mmcblk0`
- Nvme ssd: `/dev/nvme0n1`

I am copying files from an SD card to NVMe SSD, and I use `nmon` to monitor the disk activities on both devices.

I was expecting that there will be only `R` (read activity) from the source device (i.e., `/dev/mmcblk0`), but it seems there are also `W` (write activities) shown for the SD card.

[image: nmon screenshot]

Is it normal? And if it is, why?

Comment: Is the OS on the SD card?

Comment: Yes, the rootfs is on SD card.

Comment: @bruin your OS is doing the copying, it is inevitable that the OS itself will use the disk while it is running.

Comment: @mashuptwice Got it, thanks.

Comment: "*it is inevitable that the OS itself will use the disk while it is running*' -- Verify this possible explanation by monitoring the drive activity while *no* copying is performed (e.g. idle system).  Compare this drive activity with what you previously reported/posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am copying files from an SD card
> ...
> but it seems there are also W (write activities) shown for the SD card.

The metadata for each file read is being updated.
Specifically the last 'access' timestamp has to be recorded for each file that is read and copied.

You can verify that the 'access' timestamp has been updated for each file by using the [stat](https://linuxopsys.com/topics/get-last-modified-date-of-file-in-linux#1_Using_stat_command) command.
See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/344534/why-does-copying-the-same-amount-of-data-take-longer-if-spread-across-many-separ/344860#344860) that describes the drive activity for a file copy.

Since the SD card also has the rootfs, there could be some I/O activity related to the system logs and/or swap area, but normal file copying is not likely to generate log messages or induce page swapping.